# Android playing mp3 files from ListView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-emulator, android-asynctask

I have a ListView Containing list of mp3 file names need play from assets folder

if i click on any list item i need play mp3 file from assets,I'm able to play mp3 files

from assests folder

here my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if(mMediaPlayer1!=null){
            mMediaPlayer1.stop();
            mMediaPlayer1.release();
            mMediaPlayer1=null; 

        }

        mMediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();



        mMediaPlayer1.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = null;

            descriptor = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getAssets().openFd(songsList.get(position).getDescription().trim());



            mMediaPlayer1.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer1.setLooping(true);
         mMediaPlayer1.start();

    }
```

Could any one tell me how to convert this code to play the mp3 in background play?

Comment: what do you mean by background play ??

Comment: i cant understand your question? background play?